# Standarized Forms C# with inheritance

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I'm making an application for a touchscreen-computer-scanner CK3;
I made several standardized forms(list, detail, dialog) and I made em inherit from a Class I made that is inheriting from the Form class.

```
 public class Formulier : Form
{
    private const int WIDTH = 248;
    private const int HEIGHT = 328;

    public Formulier()
    {
        this.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10f);
        //this.Height = HEIGHT;
        //this.Width = WIDTH;
        //this.MinimumSize = new Size(Width, Height);
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

}
namespace WarehouseManagement {
public partial class FormPikbonDetail : Formulier {
    public FormPikbonDetail() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

It worked fine for the Font and the FormBorderStyle but the WindowState didn't get maximized. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: just guessing here but you might have to change the `WindowState` after the form is actually really created - constructor is too early.

Comment: That did it! I added  `protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }`
Thank you!

Comment: @Broken - I think you better put that as Answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change the WindowState after the form is actually really created - constructor is too early.
>   By BrokenGlass